# JSON - Grabbing full object and using a key to grab a 2nd

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I was hoping I could get some help with a problem. I don't know the exact term, perhaps nested object within an object but I was wondering how I could grab a JSON object and then also display another one as a part of the first one.

I know I would need to run a loop and assign each of the objects keys. And then use the key to grab the 2nd object to display within the first object. I'm sorry I can't explain it better ... but the output I would be looking for would be something like this :

```
"id": 1,
"name": "Mark Twain",
"username": "MTwain",
"email": "MTwain@gmail.com",
"address": "1 Street Name"
 "child": {
      "id": 3,
       "name": "Matthew A James",
       "username": "MJames",
       "email": "MJames@gmail.com",
        "address": "3 Street Name" 
     }
 }
```

From the below JSON array:

```
[
 {
"id": 1,
"name": "Mark Twain",
"username": "MTwain",
"email": "MTwain@gmail.com",
"address": "1 Street Name"

},

{
"id": 2,
"name": "Patricia Lebsack",
"username": "Karianne",
"email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
"address": "2 Street Name"
},

{
"id": 3,
"name": "Matthew A James",
"username": "MJames",
"email": "MJames@gmail.com",
"address": "3 Street Name"
  },

{
"id": 4,
"name": "Gregory Switez",
"username": "GSwitez",
"email": "GSwitez@gmail.com",
"address": "4 Street Name"
}
]
```

*EDIT*
I've made a loop that does what I want, except it displays the Object 4 times (because it's a loop obviously) ... was wondering if it could be filtered to display the object only once.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           for (var key in array[i]) {
              if(array[i].id == 1) {
              var newArray = array[i];
               newArray['objectTwo'] = array[2];
               console.log(newArray);
             }
          }
       }
```

Comment: In your output, how do you determine `id: 3` is a child of `id: 1`? In other words, what is the criterion for building the structure?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm trying to figure out how to do that. The criteria was it is to be a loop that assigns the objects keys and the key is used to identify the child object

Comment: I added a second edit to my answer including a for() loop solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming objectOne already exists, you can add an object from the JSON array as follows:

```
objectOne['objectTwo'] = JSON_Array[2]
```

Or if objectOne doesn't exist and you want to pull both objects from the array, you could do this.

```
let objectOne = JSON_Array[0]

objectOne['objectTwo'] = JSON_Array[2]
```

Hope this helps! :)

EDIT: Here is an example of using `map()` on JSON_Array in order to build an array of objects, with each object including a child object that is the next object of the current index in JSON_Array. This probably isn't exactly what you're wanting, but hopefully it can help you along the way to creating it!

```
const JSON_Array = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Mark Twain",
        "username": "MTwain",
        "email": "MTwain@gmail.com",
        "address": "1 Street Name"

    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
        "username": "Karianne",
        "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
        "address": "2 Street Name"
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Matthew A James",
        "username": "MJames",
        "email": "MJames@gmail.com",
        "address": "3 Street Name"
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Gregory Switez",
        "username": "GSwitez",
        "email": "GSwitez@gmail.com",
        "address": "4 Street Name"
    }
]

const newArray = JSON_Array.map((item, index, array) => {
    if (array[index + 1]) {
        return {
            ...item,
            child: array[index + 1]
        }
    } else {
        return item
    }
})

console.log(newArray)

/* Expected output:

[ { id: 1,
    name: 'Mark Twain',
    username: 'MTwain',
    email: 'MTwain@gmail.com',
    address: '1 Street Name',
    child: 
     { id: 2,
       name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
       username: 'Karianne',
       email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
       address: '2 Street Name' } },
  { id: 2,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
    address: '2 Street Name',
    child: 
     { id: 3,
       name: 'Matthew A James',
       username: 'MJames',
       email: 'MJames@gmail.com',
       address: '3 Street Name' } },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Matthew A James',
    username: 'MJames',
    email: 'MJames@gmail.com',
    address: '3 Street Name',
    child: 
     { id: 4,
       name: 'Gregory Switez',
       username: 'GSwitez',
       email: 'GSwitez@gmail.com',
       address: '4 Street Name' } },
  { id: 4,
    name: 'Gregory Switez',
    username: 'GSwitez',
    email: 'GSwitez@gmail.com',
    address: '4 Street Name' } ] */
```

EDIT2: And here's an example using a `for()` loop.

```
let newArray = []

const length = JSON_Array.length

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i < (length - 1)) {
        newArray.push(
            {
                ...JSON_Array[i],
                child: JSON_Array[i+1]
            }
        )
    } else {
        newArray.push(JSON_Array[i])
    }
}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: That really helps. It gets the output I was looking for, however they are looking for it to be done using a loop for this particular issue.

However I will be storing this for future work, super simple and helpful. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer adding another solution using `map()` to build a new array of objects, including a new child object in each object. Hoping it will inspire you in finding the solution you're looking for :)

Comment: Thanks ! Very helpful again. Much appreciated!

Comment: I upvoted the comment but because I don't post often it didn't appear.

Comment: Thanks :) It looks like I got some rep for it!

Comment: Ah I removed my comment because I realized if I just moved my current console.log outside of the loop it would give me the answer I was looking for. 

Although I'll try yours in the morning and I have saved ALL of that code snippets.

Thanks AGAIN, some people can kind of be dicks on SO but you've been super helpful and nice.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm new here too so I know what it can be like :P